# problem with precision and recall measuring in lucene

Tags: java, lucene

I need to calculate precision and recall value in lucene and I use this source code to do that

```
public class PrecisionRecall {

public static void main(String[] args) throws Throwable {

File topicsFile = new File("C:/Users/Raden/Documents/lucene/LuceneHibernate/LIA/lia2e/src/lia/benchmark/topics.txt");
File qrelsFile = new File("C:/Users/Raden/Documents/lucene/LuceneHibernate/LIA/lia2e/src/lia/benchmark/qrels.txt");
Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(new File("C:/Users/Raden/Documents/myindex"));
Searcher searcher = new IndexSearcher(dir, true);

String docNameField = "filename"; 

PrintWriter logger = new PrintWriter(System.out, true); 

TrecTopicsReader qReader = new TrecTopicsReader();   //#1
QualityQuery qqs[] = qReader.readQueries(            //#1
    new BufferedReader(new FileReader(topicsFile))); //#1

Judge judge = new TrecJudge(new BufferedReader(      //#2
    new FileReader(qrelsFile)));                     //#2

judge.validateData(qqs, logger);                     //#3

QualityQueryParser qqParser = new SimpleQQParser("title", "contents");  //#4

QualityBenchmark qrun = new QualityBenchmark(qqs, qqParser, searcher, docNameField);
SubmissionReport submitLog = null;
QualityStats stats[] = qrun.execute(judge,           //#5
        submitLog, logger);

QualityStats avg = QualityStats.average(stats);      //#6
avg.log("SUMMARY",2,logger, "  ");
dir.close();
}
}
```

and here is the contents of topicsfile

```
 <top>
<num> Number: 0
<title> apache source
<desc> Description:
<narr> Narrative:
</top>
```

and this is the contents of qrelsfile

```
# Format:
#
#       qnum   0   doc-name     is-relevant
#
#

0    0   apache1.0.txt       1
0    0   apache1.1.txt       1
0    0   apache2.0.txt       1
```

now the problem occur when I ran that source code which displayed the value of precision and recall to be zero. here is the result when I ran the source code.

```
0  -  contents:apache contents:source

0 Stats:
Search Seconds:         0.047
DocName Seconds:        0.039
Num Points:            56.000
Num Good Points:        0.000
Max Good Points:        3.000
Average Precision:      0.000
MRR:                    0.000
Recall:                 0.000
Precision At 1:         0.000
Precision At 2:         0.000
Precision At 3:         0.000
Precision At 4:         0.000
Precision At 5:         0.000
Precision At 6:         0.000
Precision At 7:         0.000
Precision At 8:         0.000
Precision At 9:         0.000
Precision At 10:        0.000
Precision At 11:        0.000
Precision At 12:        0.000
Precision At 13:        0.000
Precision At 14:        0.000
Precision At 15:        0.000
Precision At 16:        0.000
Precision At 17:        0.000
Precision At 18:        0.000
Precision At 19:        0.000
Precision At 20:        0.000



SUMMARY
Search Seconds:         0.047
DocName Seconds:        0.039
Num Points:            56.000
Num Good Points:        0.000
Max Good Points:        3.000
Average Precision:      0.000
MRR:                    0.000
Recall:                 0.000
Precision At 1:         0.000
Precision At 2:         0.000
Precision At 3:         0.000
Precision At 4:         0.000
Precision At 5:         0.000
Precision At 6:         0.000
Precision At 7:         0.000
Precision At 8:         0.000
Precision At 9:         0.000
Precision At 10:        0.000
Precision At 11:        0.000
Precision At 12:        0.000
Precision At 13:        0.000
Precision At 14:        0.000
Precision At 15:        0.000
Precision At 16:        0.000
Precision At 17:        0.000
Precision At 18:        0.000
Precision At 19:        0.000
Precision At 20:        0.000
```

now can you tell me what had I done wrong which make the precision and recall values to be zeros? and also what does it mean when the precision and recall value is zero? the reason I am doing this is because I need to measure the performance of my search engine, and precision and recall is one of the way for me to achieve it.

thanks though

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Precision = 0 means none of your results were correct. See [the wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Precision_%28information_retrieval%29), for example.

I would suggest trying an individual query, and see what your results are. You probably have an issue with your tokenizer; maybe you are not casing things right etc.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that the problem lies in the indexing procedure. If you look
well at

```
QualityBenchmark qrun = 
       new QualityBenchmark(qqs, qqParser, searcher, docNameField);
```

you will see that a search is launched for matches of ***both*** the ***query***
and document ***names*** (= Lucene looks up for values in the field of name `"filename"`) within the Lucene index.

This means that when you index, you need to create an ***explicit document field*** that stores the ids of the .txt files in your corpus (in your case, their names), e.g. declare

```
public static final String FIELD_NAME = "filename";
```

and then later

```
document.add(new TextField(FIELD_NAME, "apache1.0.txt", Field.Store.YES));
```

and similarly for the other 2 files. Otherwise it can't refer back
the hits to the names in the config files. I had the same problem, but after I added the new custom field, it worked like a charm :-)

**N.B.** The format of the two benchmarking config files is based on the TREC9 format; a sample `qrels.txt` file can be found at [http://trec.nist.gov/data/qrels_eng/](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/benchmark/org/apache/lucene/benchmark/quality/trec/TrecJudge.html)
and a sample `topics.txt` file at [http://trec.nist.gov/data/topics_eng/topics.501-550.txt](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/benchmark/org/apache/lucene/benchmark/quality/trec/TrecJudge.html).